# Execute sql statement

Tags: mysql, c, turbo-c

I used gcc compiler, MySQL Server 5.0
When I use a long length string as a value to insert or update or select or delete, system doesn't work. No error comes. So I could not find the error.
A part of my code is this :

```
mysql_query(conn, sql);
```

Comment: Requirements: Google.

Comment: actually i think you would have trouble linking mysql client libraries with turbo linker... especially if its 16 bit turbo c running in dosbox... :)

Comment: 1 solution would be to use a modern compiler... gcc+mingw or visual studio maybe...

Comment: just get rid of turbo c!!!

Comment: what is that?I didn't get.

Comment: Can I have the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible if you use the C driver for MySQL.